# How to use Zeal, there is nothing on the left bar, also no options on the top on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I installed Zeal on my Ubuntu 16.04 by simple command line but it's not showing any menu or anything on left bar. I'm not able to figure what to do further.

Answer (score 1):

From USC:

> Zeal is a simple offline API documentation browser inspired by Dash (OS X app), available for Linux and Windows.
>
> - Quickly search documentation using Alt+Space (or customised) hotkey to display Zeal from any place in your workspace.
> - Search in multiple sets of documentation at once.
> - Don't be dependent on your internet connection.
> - Integrate Zeal with Emacs, Sublime Text, or Vim.

---

You can type "zeal" on command line and then get an icon on the launcher that you can then fix to the launcher:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to download docsets.
 - Tools -> Docsets
 - Select your language -> Download

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation, zeal has a bug in the

> appmenu-qt5

package

You need to unstall the package first before the menu can showUp

```
$sudo apt-get purge appmenu-qt5
```

Answer (score 0):

When you open the zeal,move the mouse to the top-left corner of your computer, its choices about file and docsets appear in the top-left corner of your computer.